# How to Store Nested Objects in redis

Tags: node.js, json, object, redis, javascript-objects

What is the best way to store objects in redis and read them?
I need to store whole object and then just read whole object to pass it to a constructore

Comment: You can serialize object either as json or binary data and use **set** datatype to store using object key and **get** to fetch the object by its key

Comment: Hello fellow. Please provide more details of what you've tried so far. You are much more likely to find someone to point you in the right direction than to find someone to solve your problems.